# erroneous return value of logarithmic function stored in a static const int (c++)

Tags: c++, static, int, constants

I noticed a very strange thing in my application. There are two static const integers in my World class:

```
class World
{
  public:
    static const int CHUNK_SIZE_X = 32;
  private:
    static const int SHIFT_X;
};
```

The constant *SHIFT_X* is initialised in the corresponding *.cpp file:

```
const int World::SHIFT_X = Ogre::Math::Log2(World::CHUNK_SIZE_X);
```

Now the strange thing is that the value in *SHIFT_X* is 4 instead of 5. If I call *Ogre::Math::Log2(32)* from within an arbitrary method it correctly computes 5.

What the hell is going on here? I also need to say that this only happens under Windows 7 (with Visual Studio Express 10). My application also runs under GNU/Linux (Debian Squeeze) and there everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Ogre::Math::Log2`](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Math.html#ac453f2205d3deb1c29aa9ef806b8a9ec) returns a `Real` which is actually a `float` and you are trying to store it as an int. Therefore if the value returned was 4.9999999999999998 it would still end up with 4 after the conversion. If you would like to continue using an `int` instead of a `float` you should round the value.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. But why was the value correct after the computation from within a method? Within the method I basically wrote: int value = 32; int value2 = Ogre::Math::Log2(value); Here, value2 was 5.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Of course you're right and I feel stupid now. I should have seen that. Anyway, thank you very much for your fast help. (I still don't understand the right computation inside a method, though.)

Comment: @BrightBit I agree it is still a good question as to why it only happened in visual studio when setting the static method. It is, however, always safer to round float values when converting to int. Feel free to leave the question unanswered for a couple of days in case someone has better insight into the issue.